# Xpath with OR condition to identify an element

Tags: xpath, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to find an element using Xpath with OR condition in a website.no syntax errors are showing but the element is not getting identified.i am not able to figured it out what's wrong...?

once we launched the website either image or link will appear, target is to  click  on which is available..

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='nav-npm-footer']/div[1]/a/span or @id='multiasins-img-link']")).click();
```

code supposed to click on image or Link which is available

Comment: The square brackets in your expression aren't properly nested, so it's surprising no syntax errors are showing.

Answer (score 0):

That's not a valid xpath - it's two separate xpath expressions concatenated with "or" :)

You'd be better off locating the link and the image separately - each with its own xpath, `//*[@id='nav-npm-footer']/div[1]/a/span` and `//*[@id='multiasins-img-link']`. Thus you will also know which one was actually present, and clicked - this is probably a requirement that you also want to test...

And if you still want to do it with a single xpath, this is closer:

```
//*[@id='multiasins-img-link' or (ancestor::*[@id='nav-npm-footer']/div[1]/a and name()='span']
```

That will select either the element with that id, or one that has the name "span" and has in its ancestor path that structure - an element with id "nav-npm-footer", then div, the first of which has a. Keep in mind the "span" can be not a direct child of the "a", but a grandchild or other descendant.

And if it's needed to be specific about the span position relative to these 3 elements - this should do:

```
//*[@id='multiasins-img-link' or (name()='span' and ..[name()='a']/..[name()='div']/..[@id='nav-npm-footer'])]
```

I'd really go with two xpaths rather than down this ^ rabbit hole :)

Answer (score 0):

Not a valid xpath. Need to come with a strategy to handle such scenarios rather than using xpaths only to tackle such situations.
Ideally you should handle this with two separate xpaths and a strategy.
Try to find out which one exists or present and visible for interactions and then interact with it.
It is also good practice to have separate xpaths for different elements and before interactions always verify if the element is visible and can be interacted.

If you can share the actual HTML fragment then we can share a more appropriate way to identify the element.